# Can I use or import the functions in CharJVM.kt file which is inline function collection defined by the Kotlin platform?

Tags: kotlin

I want to make my custom inline function in .kt file using [checkRadix](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/deb416484c5128a6f4bc76c39a3d9878b38cec8c/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/kotlin/text/CharJVM.kt#L154) function already implemented by Kotlin.

But I cannot import it. How can I import and use it?

I tried

```
import kotlin.jvm.JvmMultifileClass.*
kotlin.jvm.JvmMultifileClass.checkRadix(radix)
```

But I can't compile and there is no recommended resolution by IDE.

Answer (score 2):

That function is marked as `internal`, which means it's only available within that module — i.e. within the Kotlin stdlib, not to your code.

I don't know why it's marked like that; maybe JetBrains consider it an implementation detail.  But they clearly don't want it being used by any other code.

(Of course, it wouldn't be hard to reimplement yourself.)